# What is static modularization?

Tags: oop, module, procedural-programming

I've encountered the term static modularization in an interview with Niklaus Wirth in which he said

> Nevertheless, I consider OOP as an aspect of programming in the large; that is, as an aspect that logically follows programming in the small and requires sound knowledge of procedural programming. Static modularization is the first step towards OOP. It is much easier to understand and master than full OOP, it's sufficient in most cases for writing good software, and is sadly  in most common languages (with the exception of Ada). 
>   In a way, OOP falls short of its promises.

I'm wondering what the term static modularization really means. It seems this term is not popularly used.

The full interview can be read here. http://www.eptacom.net/pubblicazioni/pub_eng/wirth.html

Comment: I suspect the father of Modula meant using modules to organize and encapsulate code without the addition of inheritance and polymorphisn.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the modula programming language. The wikipage of modula 2 makes the term quite clear for me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You should summarize an answer and accept it.